# How I will print date value inside component class in angular using matdatepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'auto'">
           <mat-label>Birth Date</mat-label>
           <input matInput       [matDatepicker]="birthDatePicker"formControlName="dateOfBirth"(dateChange)="getEndDate()">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #`enter code here`birthDatePicker>
    </mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**in component.ts **

> getEndDate(){
>       console.log(this.personForm.controls['dateOfBirth'].value);

Comment: <form [formGroup]="PersonForm">
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'auto'">
   <mat-label>Birth Date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="birthDatePicker"formControlName="dateOfBirth"(dateChange)="getEndDate()" 
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="birthDatePicker">
   </mat-datepicker-toggle></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

**change your html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"  (dateChange)="getEndDate('change', $event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="year" [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**in Ts file**

```
  getEndDate(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>){
    console.log(event.value);
  }
```

[stackBlits Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pttuhk)

Comment: This is correct code with the date field is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can access date using NgModel.
In your html file:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" placeholder="Date" 
readonly [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
(dateChange)="getDate(selectedDate)">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat- 
datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false" 
[startAt]="selectedDate" startView="month"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In your .ts file

```
selectedDate: Date = new Date();
getDate(date){
    console.log(date);
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get value like this with formGroup controls

```
getEndDate() {
  let form = this.formGroup.controls;
  let dob = form.contols["dateOfBirth"].value;
  console.log(dob);
}
```